# can't find Rust compiler to install transformers

Tags: windows, rust

I don't know how to fix this error (for pip install transformer on windows):
error: can't find Rust compiler

```
If you are using an outdated pip version, it is possible a prebuilt wheel is available for this package but pip is not able to install from it. Installing from the wheel would avoid the need for a Rust compiler.

To update pip, run:

  pip install --upgrade pip

and then retry package installation.

If you did intend to build this package from source, try installing a Rust compiler from your system package manager and ensure it is on the PATH during installation. Alternatively, rustup (available at https://rustup.rs) is the recommended way to download and update the Rust compiler toolchain.
[end of output]

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
ERROR: Failed building wheel for tokenizers
Failed to build tokenizers
ERROR: Could not build wheels for tokenizers, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

also tried this:

```bash
git clone https://github.com/huggingface/transformers.git 
cd transformers
pip install -e .
```

and when I install rust it doesn't work either.

Comment: "_when I install rust it doesn't work either_" → what happens then? How did you install Rust? And did you check that Rust is correctly in your path (e.g. by running `rustc --version`)?

Comment: I'm facing the same issue, did you find a solution?

Comment: I had the same issue when installing rasa. I had to install sentencepiece and the error did not come up again. Unfortunately I can not reproduce your error.

Answer (score 5):

You need to install Rust before installing transformers.

The standard way to install (from the [rust documentation](https://www.rust-lang.org/tools/install)) is

```
curl --proto '=https' --tlsv1.2 -sSf https://sh.rustup.rs | sh
```

On windows you can use [alternative methods](https://forge.rust-lang.org/infra/other-installation-methods.html#other-ways-to-install-rustup):

- [rustup-init.exe](https://static.rust-lang.org/rustup/dist/i686-pc-windows-gnu/rustup-init.exe)
- [standalone installers](https://forge.rust-lang.org/infra/other-installation-methods.html#standalone-installers)
- [Chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org/) or [Scoop](https://scoop.sh/)

---

Sometimes it's useful to use default answers to the installation script:

```
curl --proto '=https' --tlsv1.2 -sSf https://sh.rustup.rs | sh -s -- -y
```

Comment: If `rustup` is available through your package manager, that may also be preferable to running a shell script downloaded from the internet. Although I wouldn't recommend installing a `rustc` or `cargo` from your package manager, as those are likely very outdated

Comment: This didn't resolve the issue for me. I installed rust, updated PATH to ensure `rustc` was in my PATH and the issue persists.

Comment: Don't forget to run this: `source "$HOME/.cargo/env"` if you want it to be available right now in your current shell.